# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista con python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

[image: lista que se debe ordenar]

El orden de la lista esta en moderado, conservador y arriesgado. Al cargar la pantalla debe quedar conservador, moderado y arriesgado.

```
class FirFondoDistribucionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
"""
Administrador de las distribuciones de dichos fondos
"""
list_display = ('fondo', 'tipo_distribucion', 'porcentaje', 'is_activo', 'fecha')
```

este es el codigo de la lista

```
class FirFondoDistribucion(models.Model):
fondo = models.ForeignKey(FirFondo, null=False, blank=False, help_text='Llave foranea de Fondo', related_name='fir_fondo_distribucion')
tipo_distribucion = models.CharField('Tipo de la estrategia', max_length='5', choices=FIR_TIPO_DISTRIBUCION)
porcentaje = models.FloatField('Porcentaje', max_length=4, null=False, blank=False)
is_activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
fecha = models.DateTimeField('Fecha Creacion', auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

este es el codigo de modelo

Comment: Hola¿ Podrías agregar el método para obtener los tipos de estrategia?

Comment: Hola, no hay un método, se saca directamente de la base de datos, se hace la lista en la clase y listo. Pero dentro de esta lista necesito listar los tipos de estrategias, en conservador, moderado y arriesgado.

Comment: ¿No utlizas el ORM de Django?